# Objective-C/cocoa losing array values

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, ghosts-in-the-machine

I have multiple arrays, however, they are not retaining their data for use in another method.

Here's how I have it set up (simplified)

`.h`

```
NSArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *array;
-(void)someMethod:(NSArray*)someArray;
-(void)heresNewMethod;
```

`.m`

```
-(void)someMethod:(NSArray*)someArray
 {
array = [someArray copy];
 }
-(void)heresNewMethod //gets called by method not shown
 {
  NSLog(@"%@", array);
 }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing? Btw, you should call [array release] before storing the copy of someArray to avoid leaking the memory of the previous array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of two things happened:

- You sent the object a `someMethod:` message, passing `nil` (probably without meaning to). A message to `nil` returns `nil`, so you assigned `nil`—as the result of the `copy` message—to the `array` instance variable. Even if you had stashed a pointer to an array there previously, you replaced it with `nil` in your response to this `someMethod:` message.
- You never sent the object a `someMethod:` message. Since instance variables are initialized to `nil`, and you never put anything different in the `array` instance variable, it still contains `nil`.

Sprinkle more NSLog statements in your code to test the first theory. The truth is either one or the other, so confirming the first theory disproves the second, and vice versa.

Comment: well all be darn, it was returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the fact that you'll leak whatever was in `array` every time you call `someMethod:`, that code should work.  What's the problem you see?

Comment: @Matt: did you check that `someArray` is not `null` or `nil` before it is copied?

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is that the code you provided is not the code your using, and the difference is crucial. I mean, you declare a property which you then don't use, and it's not clear whether you are defining your accessors properly, or if array is also a local which is shadowing your property, or what.

Please post your real code.

Comment: doesn't matter, I solved the problem thanks to the great Peter Hosey